# How to install MongoDB Driver in XAMPP mac (OSX)

Tags: mongodb, xampp, osx-yosemite

I have installed mongodb and I can access it through my terminal. I want to install drivers for XAMPP in OSX (Yosemite). I downloaded mongo.so file and kept it under **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226** path which is my extension_dir pointing to and wrote **extension=mongo.so** in **php.ini** file but no luck. After restarting Apache I can't find any mongodb when I run **phpinfo()**. Please help. Maybe I just want the correct mongo.so file. Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204938/how-to-install-php-mongodb-driver-for-xampp-on-osx/30205260#30205260

Answer (score 1):

in command line...

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install mongo
```

if it gives ERROR: `phpize’ failed

Download autoconf

```
curl http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-latest.tar.gz > autoconf.tar.gz
```

Untar the autoconf archive

```
tar -xvzf autoconf.tar.gz
```

Configure and make – note the folder un-archived may have a different name.

```
cd autoconf-2.69
./configure
sudo make && sudo make install
```

This installs autoconf to ‘/usr/local/bin/autoconf’. In order to get phpize to work set the PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable to point to the newly installed autoconf.

```
export PHP_AUTOCONF=/usr/local/bin/autoconf
```

write anywhere in `php.ini`: `extension=mongo.so` (not `;extension=mongo.so` or `;extension=:"mongo.so"`) just write `extension=mongo.so`

then restart this

if you get any problem then let me know I'll for sure fix it...

Comment: I am getting the problem; please see my steps below:
1. run the command sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install mongo
2. Added extension=mongo.so to php.ini /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
3. When I am trying to restart the xampp; it stopped and never started

Comment: [suexec:notice] [pid 3870] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/suexec)
[ssl:warn] [pid 3871] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[ssl:warn] [pid 3871] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[auth_digest:notice] [pid 3871] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...

Comment: i have the same problem as well

Comment: the workaround is available here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/247