# How to Install PHP MongoDB Driver for XAMPP on OSX?

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, xampp

I entered the following commands on my command terminal in order to use the 'MongoClient' with PHP on XAMPP on my Macbook Pro:

- brew install wget
- brew install autoconf
- sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install mongo
- Added extension=mongo.so to php.ini
  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
- Restarted Apache

However, I have had no luck. I keep getting this error: Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/index.php on line 5

I'm getting kind of frustrated because I don't really know what else to try. Any advice?

Comment: Have you done this: sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-cli php-pear -y
sudo pecl install mongo

Comment: @SalvadorDali I didn't use that, but I just tried to and it said "sudo: apt-get" command not found.

Comment: forgot that you are using mac. Have you followed installation for a php driver for mac, outlined here: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php?

Comment: @SalvadorDali When I do: sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install mongo I get: "pecl/mongo is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.6.8
install failed"

Comment: CURRENT STATUS: When running "brew install php56-mongo" I get "No available formula for php56-mongo"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to start `mongod`

> brew update
>
> brew install mongodb
>
> mkdir -p /data/db
>
> mongod --dbpath /data/db

Before running `mongod` for the first time, ensure that the user account running mongod has `read` and `write` permissions for the `/data/db` directory.

Install MongoDB PHP driver

> brew install php56-mongo

OR

> sudo pecl install mongo

Comment: When I add extension=mongo.so, do I do it like this: ;extension="mongo.so" or simply like this: ;extension=mongo.so

Comment: ; means comment. So remove the ; from the beginning of the line. So it'll be extension=mongo.so

Comment: When I run: brew install php56-mongo I get : Error: No available formula for php56-mongo   how can i fix this?

Comment: It says "sudo: pecl: command not found" I'm using a Macbook pro.

Comment: Are you using MAMP? /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/pecl - this is the location of pecl on my Macbook pro for MAMP installation. The php version could be different for you. Look for /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ directory. Then run in terminal: sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/pecl install mongo

Comment: sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/pecl install mongo

downloading mongo-1.6.8.tgz ...
Starting to download mongo-1.6.8.tgz (207,879 bytes)
....................

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77679/discussion-between-adnan-and-vimzy).

Comment: on OS X El Capitan, use this command
  brew install homebrew/php/php56-mongo